# Am I able to call a submethod of a class's attribute from that class using the class as an attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am very sorry for the confusing title, I did not know how else to phrase the question.

Let's say I have a class, `A`. It is described as shown:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, argument):
        self.value = argument

    def submethod(self, argumentThatWillBeAClass):
        print(dir(argumentThatWillBeAClass))
```

And then I initialize it as shown below:

```
classAInstance = A('42.0')
```

Now, I have a class, `B`. Let's add a submethod that calls `A`'s submethod with `B` as an argument.

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, argumentThatIsAClassAInstance):
        self.classAInstance = argumentThatIsAClassAInstance

    def submethod(self):
        self.classAInstance.submethod(self)
```

Let's initialize it with `classInstance`:

```
classBInstance = B(classAInstance)
```

My desired result is that all the attributes of `B` are printed when `B.submethod` is called. Is this possible, and if not, how would I achieve something like this?

Comment: What does your current code do and how does it differ from what you’d want it to do?

Comment: Not sure why you are calling everything a submethod. They're just methods. Also, why the back and forth between `A` and `B`? What are you actually trying to model? This seems very much like an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, I have a class, B. Let's add a submethod that calls A's submethod
> with B as an argument.

But that isn't what your code does. On the following line:

```
 self.classAInstance.submethod(self)
```

You are calling the method (I don't know what you mean by "sub" method, these are all just normal methods) with *an instance of `B`, **not `B`**.

Two different ways you could do this:

```
self.classAInstance.submethod(type(self))
```

Or:

```
self.classAInstance.submethod(B)
```

The semantics aren't exactly the same, since the first dynamically retreives the instance, if some other class inherits from `B`, it will call `dir` on *that* class. The second always prints `dir(B)`, regardless of inheritance.

So:

```
class A:
    def method(self, klass: type) -> None:
        print(dir(klass))

class B:
     def __init__(self, a: A) -> None:
        self.a = a
     def method(self) -> None:
         self.a.method(type(self))

b = B(A())
```

Answer (score -1):

As one potential solution, you can use [inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance). This allows `class B` to inherit everything from `class A`

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, argument):
        self.value = argument

    def submethod(self, argumentThatWillBeAClass):
        print(dir(argumentThatWillBeAClass))

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__(value)

    def submethod(self, argumentThatWillBeAClass): # You can override the method and do extra code too. 
        super().submethod(argumentThatWillBeAClass) # Calls A's submethod function
```